# Two high side PFET switches used for bidirectional control?

Tags: mosfet, power, analog

I am seeing an issue with the following circuit in both simulator and bench.  Independent of anything I do with M1, including disconnecting R1 from the gates of M2/M3, the load powers up at the turn on of the bdpwr.  Can someone tell me how to solve this?  My expectation was to use the zener for protection and the 10uF for soft start.  I have tried adding a 1Mohm (as well as trying also a 100k) in parallel to C1/D1 at a suggestion from another but that did nothing.  Is leakage current to play here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try some more realistic component values:

[image]

In your circuit , the time constant of 10uF and 1MΩ is 10 seconds, which is pretty long for turn-on, and the discharge is only via leakage so it will not reliably ever turn off.

Note that the Vds(max) of the 2N7002 is 60V so it isn't the best choice for the small signal transistor.

Here is the turn-on with a 10uF capacitor across 3.3kΩ:

[image]

As you can see, it's mostly delay because of the relatively sharp transistor threshold.

The 10kΩ/3.3kΩ divider both acts to discharge the gate capacitance (and soft-start capacitance) predictably and limits the gate voltage to about 15V, which is well within the +/-20V Vgs(max) rating for the MOSFETs.

Comment: 10uF --- 1Mohm combo only needs to charge to Vgth but I get where you are headed.  I reduced the 60V to about 15V something more amenable to the lower NFET and tried your circuit  (10k, 3.3k and 10uF) but it still turns on with the application of voltage on bdpwr net

Comment: You want much greater than Vgs(th) = -4V unless  your load is <=250uA and a 4V voltage drop is acceptable. In which case, you wouldn't be using power MOSFETs. Is V2 = 0 (V2 in your schematic) for this test?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need the resistor in parallel with D1/C1, but commonly used circuits also tend to add two diodes across the FETs.

Have a look at this [link](https://www.ourpcb.com/bidirectional-switch.html) for an example P-FET Bidirection Power Switch (BPS), but there are many other examples.

[image]

(Image from above link.)

Comment: I tried this without D1, D2 and D3 but it too turns on when power is applied at A.  I don't get the addition of D1 and D2.  The two PFETs have an intrinisic diode that points in the complete opposite direction of D1 and D2 and defeats the whole purpose....If you read the link article they even suggest that applying power at pt A turns on the power to B which is something I am trying to avoid.  I want power to exist at A and ONLY come on with the ON/OFF switch